# Laravel Homestead Not Accepting Key Pairs

Tags: laravel, vagrant

I have just started trying to set up an instance of homestead. I have been successful so far but I am a bit confused on the current step. I am on a windows machine so have mapped my `homestead.yaml` ssh key paths to the full windows paths and have confirmed their existence/location. Now when I attempt to ssh into my vagrant box, I am prompted for a password. The default `"vagrant"` password works but I was under the impression that the ssh keys would handle my sign on.

Here is a look at my `homestead.yaml`

---

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox //This is my provider

authorize: C:/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:/PROGRA~1/Laravel/Homestead/projects/website
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/website

sites:
    - map: website.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/website/public

databases:
    - website

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are on a windows machine you need to fix your slashes.

```
authorize: C:\Users\me\.ssh\id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:\Users\me\.ssh\id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\PROGRA~1\Laravel\Homestead\projects\website
      to: /home/vagrant/projects/website
```

and the rest is correct.